# Convert string to json where some values are wrapped in square brackets

Tags: python, string-conversion

What would be the most efficient way (python 3) to convert a `string` to `dict`, where some of the keys and values may or may not be quoted and some values may contain sub objects wrapped in square brackets (`[]`) instead of curly ones.

Also values may contain colon (`:`) in them

Example:

`string = "[key:value, key2:[key2a:val2:a, key2b:[foo:"bar"]]]"`

the results needs to be a valid `dict` like:

`{"key":"value", "key2":{"key2a":"val2:a", "key2b":{"foo":"bar"}}}`

Comment: How do you tell when brackets mean a dict and when they mean a list?  How do you tell what needs to be in quotes and what doesn't?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You need to fully specify your problem and post your coding attempt.  Your posted input isn't legal Python: you say that you have a string, but your RHS in that first line is some illegal sequence attempt.

Comment: @ScottHunter the assumption is that no lists are passed. anything in square brackets is to be converted to a dict inside the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import re
string = "[key:value, key2:[key2a:val2:a, key2b:[foo:'bar']]]"
d = [i if not i.startswith("'") else i[1:-1] for i in re.findall("[\[\]]|:|'.*?'|\w+|,", string)[1:-1]]
def to_dict(d):
   while (n:=next(d, None)) not in {None, ']'}:
      _ = next(d)
      if (v:=next(d)) == '[':
         v = dict(to_dict(d))
      else:
         c = [v]
         while (j:=next(d)) not in {',', ']'}:
            c.append(j)
         if j == ']':
            d = iter([*d, j])
         v = ''.join(c)
      yield (n, v)

print(dict(to_dict(iter(d))))
```

Output:

```
{'key': 'value', 'key2': {'key2a': 'val2:a', 'key2b': {'foo': 'bar'}}}
```

Edit: solution without assignment expressions (`:=` walrus operator):

```
def to_dict(d):
   n = next(d, None)
   while n not in {None, ']'}:
      _, v = next(d), next(d)
      if v == '[':
         v = dict(to_dict(d))
      else:
         c, j = [v], next(d)
         while j not in {',', ']'}:
            c.append(j)
            j = next(d)
         if j == ']':
            d = iter([*d, j])
         v = ''.join(c)
      yield (n, v)
      n = next(d, None)


print(dict(to_dict(iter(d))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Any chance for a python 3.6 version of this solution as well? (i.e without the walrus operator)

Comment: One more obstacle i forgot to mention (i will update the question as well) some values may also contain colon, for example `[key: 'some:value']`

Comment: @Gil Please see my recent edit, I updated the regular expression.

Comment: I may not have expressed myself well enough, please bare with me... the values do not always have quotes. so a value can be 'some:string' or some:string. I appreciate your help on this!

Comment: @Gil Please see my recent edit, I updated both solutions.